# PySimpleGUI that generates a table of summary statistics and histogram in one plot

Tags: python, user-interface, pysimplegui

I'm having a problem in Python. Please see below code. It generates a summary statistics in the console and a histogram plot. However, I want to create a GUI using PySimpleGUi that will provide a GUI allowing users to change parameters to the plot and as a result, generate new histogram plots and summary statistics each time. I am clueless how to proceed with this as I am quite new to Python and Stack Overflow. I'd like a user interface to appear when the code is run, asking users to change the parameters in the equation used to generate the dataset that plots the histogram.
`

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter


def read_table():
    sg.set_options(auto_size_buttons=True)
    filename = sg.popup_get_file(
        'Dataset to read',
        title='Dataset to read',
        no_window=True,
        file_types=(("CSV Files", ".csv"), ("Text Files", "*.txt")))
    # --- populate table with file contents --- #
    if filename == '':
        return

    colnames_prompt = sg.popup_yes_no('Does this file have column names already?')
    nan_prompt = sg.popup_yes_no('Drop NaN entries?')

    if filename is not None:
        fn = filename.split('/')[-1]
        try:
            if colnames_prompt == 'Yes':
                df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', engine='python')
                # Uses the first row (which should be column names) as columns names
                header_list = list(df.columns)
                # Drops the first row in the table (otherwise the header names and the first row will be the same)
                data = df[1:].values.tolist()
            else:
                df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', engine='python', header=None)
                # Creates columns names for each column ('column0', 'column1', etc)
                header_list = ['column' + str(x) for x in range(len(df.iloc[0]))]
                df.columns = header_list
                # read everything else into a list of rows
                data = df.values.tolist()
            # NaN drop?
            if nan_prompt == 'Yes':
                df = df.dropna()

            return df, data, header_list, fn
        except:
            sg.popup_error('Error reading file')
            return


def show_table(data, header_list, fn):
    layout = [
        [sg.Table(values=data,
                  headings=header_list,
                  font='Helvetica',
                  pad=(25, 25),
                  display_row_numbers=False,
                  auto_size_columns=True,
                  num_rows=min(25, len(data)))]
    ]

    window = sg.Window(fn, layout, grab_anywhere=False)
    event, values = window.read()
    window.close()


def show_stats(df):
    stats = df.describe().T
    header_list = list(stats.columns)
    data = stats.values.tolist()
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        d.insert(0, list(stats.index)[i])
    header_list = ['Summary Statistics'] + header_list
    layout = [
        [sg.Table(values=data[12:],
                  headings=header_list,
                  font='Helvetica',
                  pad=(12, 12),
                  display_row_numbers=False,
                  auto_size_columns=True,
                  num_rows=min(25, len(data)))]
    ]

    window = sg.Window("Statistics", layout, grab_anywhere=False)
    event, values = window.read()
    window.close()


def plot_fig(df):
    """
    Plots
    """
    # Identify link to arrays
    input_file = r"input_csv_files/testfile.csv"

    # Read input files using pandas dataframe
    data_hss = pd.read_csv(input_file, na_values=':', usecols=['result1'])
    data_sp = pd.read_csv(input_file, na_values=':', usecols=['result2'])

    # Read input files from one file
    data = pd.read_csv(input_file, na_values=':', usecols=['result1', 'result2'])

    # Prepare files by eliminating NaN values
    dataDrop_hss = data_hss.dropna(how='any', subset=['result1'], axis=0)
    dataDrop_sp = data_sp.dropna(how='any', subset=['result2'], axis=0)

    # Make a separate list for each histogram
    hss = list(dataDrop_hss['result1'])
    s_p = list(dataDrop_sp['result2'])

    # Assign colors to each histogram and the legend names
    colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange']
    names = ['hss', 'sp']

    # Plot the histogram
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.hist([hss, s_p], bins=20, label=names, color=colors)
    ax1.set_xlim(-0.14, 0.30)
    ax1.set_ylim(0, 120)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))

    # Format the plots
    plt.xlabel('Return')
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.title('hss and sp')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')

    # ------------------------------- END OF YOUR MATPLOTLIB CODE -------------------------------

    # ------------------------------- Beginning of Matplotlib helper code -----------------------

    def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
        figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
        figure_canvas_agg.draw()
        figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
        return figure_canvas_agg

    # ------------------------------- Beginning of GUI CODE -------------------------------

    # Define the window layout
    layout = [[sg.Text('Plot test')],
              [sg.Canvas(key='-CANVAS-')],
              [sg.Button('Ok')]]

    # create the form and show it without the plot
    window = sg.Window('graph', layout, location=(0, 0), finalize=True, element_justification='center',
                       font='Helvetica 18', resizable=True)

    # Add the plot to the window
    draw_figure(window['-CANVAS-'].TKCanvas, fig)

    event, values = window.read()

    window.close()


def main():
    df, data, header_list, fn = read_table()

    # Show data?
    show_prompt = sg.popup_yes_no('Show the dataset?')
    if show_prompt == 'Yes':
        show_table(data, header_list, fn)

    # Show stats?
    stats_prompt = sg.popup_yes_no('Show the descriptive stats?')
    if stats_prompt == 'Yes':
        show_stats(df)

    # Show a plot?
    plot_prompt = sg.popup_yes_no('Show a histogram plot?')
    if plot_prompt == 'Yes':
        plot_fig(df)


# Executes main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`

Here is the output I get for summary stats but I got no user interface for users to change input variables to manipulate charts and summary stats

histogram:

[image: histogram]

summary stats:

[image: summary stats]

Comment: maybe first create GUI with some Entry/Input/Text fields for parameters and with Button to run function which will get parameters from widgets and make calculations.

Comment: Thanks. Here is my problem. I can see how to create the GUI but how do you make the buttons to be able to use the input parameters to make calculations? In other words, how do you link the user input to the function definitions which perform the calculation?

Comment: you don't link it - every widget has own `key` and Button should run function which gets values from widgets and run your calculation with values.

Comment: Thanks. For example, when i run my code, i get the interface shown by @Jason Yang. But if I click on the histogram bar, nothing happens. The show statistics bar produces expected output. What `key` do i need to put there?

Comment: did you run it in console to see error messages? Did you add your function to code in answer? If you didn't add then it may display error message in console instead expected windows. And see code in answer - there is `key` in `Input(key='Dataset')` and later it uses `event, values = window.read()` to get all values from GUI and `values["Dataset"]` to get value from `Input(key='Dataset')` - so it uses the same `Dataset` which it has as `key='Dataset'` in `Input()`

Answer (score 1):

You need spend time to design the GUI for your application, one main window if possible.

Following show the example for you

```py
from pathlib import Path

import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.ticker import PercentFormatter


def load_dataset(filename, headings, nan):

    if not Path(filename).is_file():
        return None
    window['Status'].update('file loading ...')
    window.refresh()

    try:
        if headings:
            df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', engine='python')
            header_list = list(df.columns)
            data = df[1:].values.tolist()
        else:
            df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', engine='python', header=None)
            header_list = ['column' + str(x) for x in range(len(df.iloc[0]))]
            df.columns = header_list
            data = df.values.tolist()
        if nan:
            df = df.dropna()
        window['Status'].update('File loaded')
        return df, data, header_list, Path(filename).name
    except:
        window['Status'].update('Error reading file')
        return None


def show_table(data, header_list, fn):

    layout = [
        [sg.Table(values=data,
                  headings=header_list,
                  font='Helvetica',
                  pad=(25, 25),
                  display_row_numbers=False,
                  auto_size_columns=True,
                  num_rows=min(25, len(data)))]
    ]

    sg.Window(fn, layout).read(close=True)

def show_statistics(df):

    stats = df.describe().T
    header_list = list(stats.columns)
    data = stats.values.tolist()
    for i, d in enumerate(data):
        d.insert(0, list(stats.index)[i])
    header_list = ['Summary Statistics'] + header_list

    layout = [
        [sg.Table(values=data[12:],
                  headings=header_list,
                  font='Helvetica',
                  pad=(12, 12),
                  display_row_numbers=False,
                  auto_size_columns=True,
                  num_rows=min(25, len(data)))]
    ]

    sg.Window("Statistics", layout).read(close=True)

def show_histogram(df):
    """
    Plots
    """
    # Identify link to arrays
    input_file = r"input_csv_files/testfile.csv"

    # Read input files using pandas dataframe
    data_hss = pd.read_csv(input_file, na_values=':', usecols=['result1'])
    data_sp = pd.read_csv(input_file, na_values=':', usecols=['result2'])

    # Read input files from one file
    data = pd.read_csv(input_file, na_values=':', usecols=['result1', 'result2'])

    # Prepare files by eliminating NaN values
    dataDrop_hss = data_hss.dropna(how='any', subset=['result1'], axis=0)
    dataDrop_sp = data_sp.dropna(how='any', subset=['result2'], axis=0)

    # Make a separate list for each histogram
    hss = list(dataDrop_hss['result1'])
    s_p = list(dataDrop_sp['result2'])

    # Assign colors to each histogram and the legend names
    colors = ['tab:blue', 'tab:orange']
    names = ['hss', 'sp']

    # Plot the histogram
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.hist([hss, s_p], bins=20, label=names, color=colors)
    ax1.set_xlim(-0.14, 0.30)
    ax1.set_ylim(0, 120)
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(PercentFormatter(1))

    # Format the plots
    plt.xlabel('Return')
    plt.ylabel('Count')
    plt.title('hss and sp')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')

    # ------------------------------- END OF YOUR MATPLOTLIB CODE -------------------------------

    # ------------------------------- Beginning of Matplotlib helper code -----------------------

    def draw_figure(canvas, figure):
        figure_canvas_agg = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, canvas)
        figure_canvas_agg.draw()
        figure_canvas_agg.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
        return figure_canvas_agg

    # ------------------------------- Beginning of GUI CODE -------------------------------

    # Define the window layout
    layout = [[sg.Text('Plot test')],
              [sg.Canvas(key='-CANVAS-')],
              [sg.Button('Ok')]]

    # create the form and show it without the plot
    window = sg.Window('graph', layout, location=(0, 0), finalize=True, element_justification='center',
                       font='Helvetica 18', resizable=True)

    # Add the plot to the window
    draw_figure(window['-CANVAS-'].TKCanvas, fig)

    window.read(close=True)


layout = [
    [sg.Text("Dateset"),
     sg.Checkbox("With column names", enable_events=True, key="Headings"),
     sg.Checkbox("Drop NaN entries", enable_events=True, key="NaN")],
    [sg.Input(key='Dataset'), sg.FileBrowse()],
    [sg.Button("Show Dataset"), sg.Button("Show Statistics"), sg.Button("Show Histogram")],
    [sg.StatusBar('', size=20, expand_x=True, key='Status')],
]

window = sg.Window("Dataset", layout, finalize=True)
filename = None
load = False
while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    if filename != values["Dataset"] or event in ("Headings", "NaN"):
        filename, headings, nan = values["Dataset"], values['Headings'], values['NaN']
        result = load_dataset(filename, headings, nan)
        if result:
            load = True
            df, data, header_list, fn = result
        else:
            load = False
    if not load:
        continue
    if event == "Show Dataset":
        show_table(data, header_list, fn)
    elif event == "Show Statistics":
        show_statistics(df)
    elif event == "Show Histogram":
        show_histogram(df)

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Jason. This helps with generating the GUI. Using this, I defined my functions in the scripts but somehow, the buttons are not linked to the functions. For example, when I click histogram, after defining my function, nothing happens. Is there like a command I need to call in my code to allow this to happen?

Comment: Hello @Jason Yang an @furas, what key do I need to add to this interface to enable the histogram to be activated when I click it? I'm struggling to understand that concept. Any insight will be appreciated. I'm surprised that the 'Show Statistics' button is able to run without any assigned `key`, but the 'Show Histogram` button won't run when clicked.

Comment: The 1st option `button_text` of `sg.Button` will be used as key of this button if both of options `key` and `k` not specified. Get `event` and `values` from `window.read()`, `event` will be the key of button when button pressed. Be careful about the spell of button text and the text used to compare with `event`, they should be the same and case sensitive.

Comment: Should be care about that the key can not duplicate in a window, or the key will be replaced by key with index implicitly.

Comment: This sounds trivial, but I have struggled for several hours with defining these functions the way I know as shown in my code above but I am getting errors. The keys are not responding to clicks. I like how you presented the solution. Looks readable. Would you be kind enough to define some of these functions: def load_dataset(filename, headings, nan):
    print(filename, headings, nan)
    return ("df", "data", "header_list", "fn") or None   and  def show_table(data, header_list, fn):
    print("Show Table")........ @Jason Yang

Comment: Just add your code into my example code, not tested and maybe something wrong, IMO, you can revise it by yourself.